# A specific column is not being inserted when saving a record

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working with **CakePHP 1.3.13**. Here I have writen a code to insert form in to database.

Here, deals database table looks like below.

[image]

When I insert record into database so voucher_code column is not inserted.

Here when I print $this->data then it will gives all data like :

```
Array
(
[Deal] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deal title
        [original_price] => 350
        [discount] => 45
        [total_price] => 192.5
        [voucher_code] => TEST3211
        [redeem_points] => 158
        [deal_details] => tetert
        [condition] => Testing
        [deal_address] => tertre
        [deal_end_date] => 2016-05-26
        [no_of_deals] => 10
        [merchant_id] => 24
        [image] => 146399768856085.jpg
    )

)
```

Here I have write insert query like :

```
 $this->Deal->create();
 $this->Deal->save($this->data);
```

So all column's are inserted except **voucher_code**. So what will be the error ? and How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Wild guess: the `voucher_code` column was added to the schema just recently, ie it wasn't present when the table was created initially?

Comment: @ndm Yes, I have added this column after creating table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only those columns/fields will be saved that are present in the cached database table schema, so when adding fields after CakePHP has already cached it, you'll have to clear the cache (delete `app/tmp/cache/models`) in order for the new columns to be recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying

```
app/Config/core.php 
Config::write('debug',2);
```

Refreshing a page and restoring

```
Config::write('debug');
```

to original value will also work.

Answer (score 0):

this is very common  issue goto tmp folder of your project and delete all the cache under model and persistent folder and re run your query and it start works.